# Why don't UiKit components accept angular inputs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input, uikit

I'm trying to pass a Boolean as input as follows:

```
import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: "dac-accordion",
    templateUrl: "./dac-accordion.html",
})

export class DacAccordion implements OnInit {

    @Input("dac-collapse")
    collapse: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(">>>>>>> ", this.collapse); //This prints false.
        UIkit.accordion($("#accordion"), { collapse: this.collapse});
    }

}
```

When I print out the value of "this.collapse" it prints "false" because I'm passing it using the @Input directive in angular2.

But this seems not to work in this code snippet.

It only works if I explicitly tried to pass it like follows:

```
UIkit.accordion($("#accordion"), { collapse: false });
```

What is going on?! Is it something with the UiKit itself?!

Comment: Where is the class definition?

Comment: @TiepPhan Didn't work.

Comment: @TiepPhan Also didn't work, this is weird. Isn't it?

Comment: Why are you even using jQuery within angular?

Comment: @TiepPhan I don't think this is the problem, as I mentioned in my post it works when I explicitly pass 'false' to that option, so I think the DOM does exist.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's because Uikit doesn't support angular.

Comment: Why not? Does UIKit require jQuery? If not, just pass the DOM object directly in.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried doing this but also failed.

Comment: @TiepPhan check out my answer.

Comment: @evolutionxbox check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because in Angular if I write `input="false"`, this input is passed to the component input as 'String' and not as 'Boolean', so when I print collapse value it prints "False", but not Boolean. So basically I've converted the string value of "collapse" to Boolean and pass it to the component options and it worked.